# How to lower brightness beyond minimum for laptop screen in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: brightness, 22.04, xrandr, backlight, night-light

### Problem

My laptop's screen remains too bright at night, even at the minimum brightness.

### Solution I'd like

A tool that lets me change brightness beyond minimum brightness.

### What I've tried already

1. [xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/a/909392/1190812): Brightness remains the same regardless of the value I enter.
2. [xgamma](https://superuser.com/a/980676): Again, brightness doesn't change no matter what number I enter.
3. [Brightness Controller](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/install-brightness-controller-utility-in-ubuntu-16-04-higher/): Does not work in Ubuntu 22.04.
4. [Redshift](https://linoxide.com/install-and-use-redshift-on-ubuntu-20-04/): No longer functional.
5. [Night Light](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246195/how-to-turn-on-night-light-blue-light-filter-in-ubuntu-20-04): Only changes color, not backlight or brightness, even if artificially.

Comment: Try "light", available in the Ubuntu repositories

Comment: Most likely your tools are not working because you are using Wayland, and they are designed for Xorg. If you [switch to xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04), most of these options should work.

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome Shell extension [Alpha Tint](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4624/alphatint/) has solved the issue for me in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Wayland).