# Dimm my screen light from software while keeping night light

Tags: screen, brightness, night-light

I like night light (build-in setting in my ubuntu 20.04), but it doesn't reduce screen brightess enough.

Is there a command / tool I could use to dimm my screen further, while keeping the night light orage tint ?

Comment: I don't just use a single desktop, thus use `redshift` (*or GUI front-ends like `redshift-gtk`) so I have the same settings for whatever desktop I decide to login with, but it allows me to set values for day & night, and not just when redshift is fully operating (ie. *night* mode like your existing program). I've not fully explored night light as it's GNOME specific.

Comment: `redshift -P -O <colorTemps> -b <brightness> `works well, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be changing the brightness from the terminal using the built in `xrandr` command and a cron job say at 6pm to reduce the brightness and 7am to increase it.

Type `xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "` in terminal to fetch the name of the attached display to your Ubuntu system. Then use this command format, `xrandr --output [display-name] --brightness [level of illumination]` to set the preferred levels eg. `xrandr --output VGA-1 --brightness 0.5`.
It might be easier to create two different shell scripts for this - one for day & the other for night.

**UPDATE**

You can turn the night light on in the same scripts in-case adjusting your brightness turns off the night light using `gsettings` - [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246195/how-to-turn-on-night-light-blue-light-filter-in-ubuntu-20-04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291156/1582095)

1. [How to change screen brightness in ubuntu using command terminal](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-change-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-using-command-terminal.html)
2. [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Comment: thanks, but on my ubutnu 20.04 unfortunately this approach remove the "night light" orange tint

Comment: I didn't think that would happen. I have updated the answer - seems you can also turn it on using the terminal

Comment: Thanks, but turning on gnome night light seems to turn off screen dimmer and vice versa.
I installed redshift and it works well :)